# How to use ParameterGrid to take multiple lists as inputs, to iterate through all combinations and input results to a function to test all options

Tags: python, for-loop, scikit-learn, iteration

I have a function i created that has miltiple inputs such as start date, period, variable name etc. currently i have to manually input values into the function to allow it to begin running but i would like to try and automate this. some of the inputs are constant and dont need to be changed while others do to vary the result.

and the inputs i want to change using the iterators are:

```
train_period = [1, 4, 16, 39]

###The different test periods
test_start = ['2014-01-01 00:00', '2014-07-01 00:00']

###The different response variables
test_var = ['Temperature']

###Different step-ahead
step_ahead = [1, 4, 16, 96]

###Whether to consider smoothing or not
smoothing = [True, False]

###Define the grid of parameters to search
hyper_grid = {'train_period': train_period,
              'test_start': test_start, 
              'test_var': test_var,
              'step_ahead': step_ahead,
              'smoothing': smoothing}

from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
```

I did try using parametergrid to change using a forloop but its not working unfortunately

```
grid = ParameterGrid(hyper_grid)
for params in grid:
    results dataframe format based on for loop index= Function(params['train_period'], params['test_start'], params['test_var'], params['step_ahead'], params['smoothing'])
```

the result should replace the values in the function side of the code below other than the fixed values.

```
result1, result2, result3 = Function(fixedvalue1, fixedvalue2, train_period, test_start, test_period, test_var, step_ahead, smoothing = False)
```

Comment: What did the ParameterGrid give in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html), you could call `list()` on `grid` and your `for` loop would work, but you would need to index your results or do something with them (e.g. save the performance metric) before the next iteration of the loop.

```
grid = list(ParameterGrid(hyper_grid))
for params in grid:
    results = Function(params['train_period'], params['test_start'], params['test_var'], params['step_ahead'], params['smoothing'])
```

Comment: only took a small change but got it fixed. just needed to save the results to a list and append them to previous result to get the desired result. thanks for your input